# Uncaught TypeError: o.intersection is not a function in turf.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, turf

I'm working on a buffer analysis and then intersection using turf.js. I have a buffered output layer to which I need to intersect another polygon layer and get the output. Below is my code,

```
        function calculateBuffer() {
            var fc1 = turf.featureCollection(fc1Layer.getLayers().map(function(f){
                    return f.toGeoJSON()
                }));



            var buffer = turf.buffer(fc1, 5, 'kilometers');
            buffer.properties = {
                "fill": "#6BC65F",
                "stroke": "#25561F",
                "stroke-width": 2
            };
            bufferLayer.setGeoJSON(buffer);
           //var bufferGeojson=bufferLayer.setGeoJSON(buffer);
    //polygon layer//
            var fc = turf.featureCollection(fcLayer.getLayers().map(function(f){
                    return f.toGeoJSON()
                }));
    //buffer layer//
             var buffer = turf.featureCollection(bufferLayer.getLayers().map(function(f){
                    return f.toGeoJSON()
                }));
  //intersection//       
            var polygon = turf.intersect(fc,buffer);
        polygon.properties = {
            "fill": "#25561F",
            "stroke": "#25561F",
            "stroke-width": 10
        };
        intersectLayer.setGeoJSON(polygon);
        }
```

I'm getting the following error:turf.min.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: o.intersection is not a function. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: when debugging don't use the minified versions of the library

Comment: <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js"></script>

Comment: This is the one I'm using

Comment: Please use `turf.js` and **not** `turf.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`turf.intersect()`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) takes only single features with `Polygon` geometry as arguments.

You should separate your layers into individual Polygons and compute the intersection between your 2 sets of Polygons by iteration.

Comment: As you said I took two individual polygons and tried intersection as two different geojson file. but still it gives me the same error.

Comment: Please would you be able to reproduce your issue on an online editing service, like Plunker, JSFiddle, JSBin, etc.?